# Homemade NAU7802 breakout board not preforming like reference

Tags: adc, load-cell

I am designing an NAU7802 breakout PCB for a small weight scale project I'm working on, but I've had bad luck getting it working. I am comparing its performance with the Sparkfun Quiic Scale (their NAU7802 breakout board). My board is based on their schematic and board layout.

The following graphs show data collected with each board over ~five minutes at 10Hz with steady state conditions. Gain = 128, input voltage = 3.3v. The same 3kg load cell and micro controller are used to collect the data from both breakout boards. This data is representative of many trials I’ve conducted.

[image: Homemade NAU7802 data]
[image: Sparkfun NAU7802 data]

You can see that the data from my board is much less stable than the Sparkfun board, in addition to being negative. Again, the same load cell and MCU are used to collect data from both boards.

Here is my schematic, board layout, and assembled PCB:

[image: Homemade NAU7802 schematic]
[image: Homemade NAU7802 board layout]
[image: Homemade NAU7802 board assembly]

Linked are the specific components I’m using on my board:

- U1: [NAU7802](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/nuvoton-technology-corporation-of-america/NAU7802SGI/2769782)
- C8, C9, C10: [0.1uF cap](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/samsung-electro-mechanics/CL10B104JB8NNNC/3886691?s=N4IgTCBcDaIIxgOwDYC0cAMBmL7UDkARQOAIQBdAXyA)
- C11: [330pF cap](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/walsin-technology-corporation/0603N331J500CT/9355017?s=N4IgTCBcDaIIxgJxgLRwKxgAxpQOQBEQBdAXyA)
- C12: [1uF cap](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/samsung-electro-mechanics/CL10A105KA8NNNC/3886760?s=N4IgTCBcDaKHAEBGMB2AbAWgQgDGT6A5AEThAF0BfIA)
- R2, R3: [2.2k ohm resistor](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/stackpole-electronics-inc/RMCF0603JT2K20/1758069)
- R9, R10: [47 ohm resistor](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/stackpole-electronics-inc/RMCF0603FT47R0/1761141)

I would appreciate any help I could get. Thanks!

**Edit 1:**

```
#include "SparkFun_Qwiic_Scale_NAU7802_Arduino_Library.h"
NAU7802 myScale; //Create instance of the NAU7802 class

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("NAU7802 Test Code");
  
  Wire.begin();

  if (myScale.begin() == false)
  {
    Serial.println("Scale not detected. Please check wiring. Freezing...");
    while (1);
  }
  //myScale.reset();
  myScale.setGain(NAU7802_GAIN_128);
  myScale.setSampleRate(NAU7802_SPS_10);

  myScale.setBit( 2, 0x02 ); // Set bit = 1 to start cal
  int calCheck = 1;
  while( calCheck == 1 ){ // check status bit and exit when cal is done
    //Serial.println( "waiting for NAU7802 calibration" );
    delay(10);
    calCheck = myScale.getBit( 2, 0x02 );
    //Serial.println( "calCheck: " + String( calCheck ) );
  }
  
  Serial.println("Scale detected!");
  Serial.println( "Zero offset set: " + String( myScale.getZeroOffset() ) );
  Serial.println( "Calibration factor set: " + String( myScale.getCalibrationFactor() ) );
  Serial.println( "CAL_ERR: " + String( myScale.getBit(3, 0x00) ) );
}

void loop()
{
  if(myScale.available() == true)
  {
    long currentReading = myScale.getReading();
    Serial.println(currentReading);
  }
}
```

Here's a startup cycle from my homemade board:

[image: Homemade board startup cycle]

And this is from the sparkfun:

[image: Sparkfun board startup cycle]

**Edit 2:**

Some comments prompted me to inspect the offset calibration and gain calibration registers of the NAU7802. Below are are those values. It's interesting that the offset value are so consistent on the sparkfun boars, vs the inconsistent values from my homemade board. Im not sure what would cause this, though...

[image: NAU7802 offset and gain calibration data]

As I was exploring this, I started getting i2c errors from my MCU (NodeMCU ESP32-S, V1.1). The logs read:

```
[E][esp32-hal-i2c.c:318] i2cDumpI2c(): i2c=0x3ffbdbb4
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:319] i2cDumpI2c(): dev=0x60013000 date=0x16042000
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:321] i2cDumpI2c(): lock=0x3ffb8440
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:323] i2cDumpI2c(): num=0
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:324] i2cDumpI2c(): mode=1
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:325] i2cDumpI2c(): stage=3
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:326] i2cDumpI2c(): error=1
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:327] i2cDumpI2c(): event=0x3ffb84c4 bits=200
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:328] i2cDumpI2c(): intr_handle=0x3ffb84f4
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:329] i2cDumpI2c(): dq=0x3ffb84a0
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:330] i2cDumpI2c(): queueCount=1
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:331] i2cDumpI2c(): queuePos=0
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:332] i2cDumpI2c(): errorByteCnt=0
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:333] i2cDumpI2c(): errorQueue=0
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:334] i2cDumpI2c(): debugFlags=0x00000000
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:311] i2cDumpDqData(): Debug Buffer not Enabled
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:354] i2cDumpInts(): Debug Buffer not Enabled
[I][esp32-hal-i2c.c:1130] i2cProcQueue(): Bus busy, reinit
[D][esp32-hal-i2c.c:1336] i2cProcQueue():  Busy Timeout start=0x588db, end=0x5890d, =50, max=50 error=1
```

This will loop several times, then either crash, or measure zero (0), or return to measuring values as 'normal'. I have no idea why it's doing this, and why I'm seeing this now. As far as I can tell, this only happens on my homemade board, not the Sparkfun board.

Comment: Given that the NAU7802 is a 24 bit ADC, and given that you are off by approx 3,000,000, I am guessing that there is something funky going on with bit order or bit flipping. Also, the NAU7802 is dual channel. Are you sure you are reading the correct channel?

Comment: Does your mcu check the calibration error register of the NAU7802 after start-up? See section 8.6 page20-21 of the data sheet. https://www.nuvoton.com/export/resource-files/NAU7802%20Data%20Sheet%20V1.7.pdf

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy thanks for your reply. I should have mentioned in my original post that I'm using the Sparkfun NAU7802 library for my tests. I took a look at the section you suggested and implemented some checks in my code. Interestingly enough, after initiating a calibration cycle on startup, the error bit on both boards, my homemade board and the Sparkfun reference, report an error (1). I will update my original post with my code sample.

Comment: Interesting. Don't know why you get calibration errors. What code prints the "e" or "ts" before the "Scale Detected"?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy yes it's a stumper. I think the 'e' and 'ts' was showing up because there was some extra characters in the serial buffer. Coming back to it now (a few power cycles), it's not doing it. All other results still the same.

Comment: Section 8.6.3 of https://www.digikey.jp/htmldatasheets/production/1340443/0/0/1/nau7802-datasheet.html only lists two possible cases for calibration error. Can you investigate these two possibilities?

Comment: @MathKeepsMeBusy I took a look at that section and the wording is not exactly clear to me. I think it refers to the values stored in the offset calibration and gain calibration registers. I wrote some code to log these values just after I call the getCalibrationFactor() function. I'll edit my original post to add these values. Also a funny thing that started happening, occasionally I see i2c errors when my homemade board is connected. Sometimes following this the the board with measure 0. Will include more details about this above as this comment is getting too long...